# Tuning of mtry by caret returning strange value

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I tune the `mtry` parameter of `randomForest` using the `train` function from the `caret` package. There are only `48` columns in my `X` data, however `train` returns `mtry=50` as the best value whereas this is not a valid value (`>48`). What is the explanation of that ?

```
> dim(X)
[1] 93 48
> fit <- train(level~., data=data.frame(X,level), tuneLength=13) 
> fit$finalModel

Call:
 randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 50

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 2.15%
Confusion matrix:
     high low class.error
high   81   1  0.01219512
low     1  10  0.09090909
```

It is even worse if I don't set the `tuneLength` parameter:

```
> fit <- train(level~., data=data.frame(X,level)) 
> fit$finalModel 

Call:
 randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 55

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 2.15%
Confusion matrix:
     high low class.error
high   81   1  0.01219512
low     1  10  0.09090909
```

I don't provide the data cause it is confidential. But there's nothing special in these data: each column is numerical or is a factor, and there are no missing value.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without reproducible data.  As a first thought, you can check `fit$modelInfo$grid(X, level, 13)` to make sure something strange isn't happening with the grid generation.

Comment: Thank you @charles. The highest value in the output of `fit$modelInfo$grid(X, level, 13)` is `48`.

Comment: Try a generic random matrix with`set.seed(1234)` and `X <- matrix(rep(rep(rnorm(48)), 93), nrow=93)` and induce classification `X[1:82,] <- X[1:82,] + 0.5` and `X[83:93,] <- X[83:93,] - 0.5`.  This is very crude but should work for these purposes.  Run the same analysis.  This should return only 5 variables at each split to make sure everything is working normally.  Also, perhaps you could share the `str` of your data (feel free to rename columns to X1-X48) so we can try and mimic it as closely as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apparent discrepancy is most likely[1] between the number of columns in your data set and the number of predictors, which may not be the same if any of the columns are factors. You used the formula method, which will expand the factors into dummy variables. For example:

```
> head(model.matrix(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = iris))
  (Intercept) Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width Speciesversicolor Speciesvirginica
1           1          5.1          1.4         0.2                 0                0
2           1          4.9          1.4         0.2                 0                0
3           1          4.7          1.3         0.2                 0                0
4           1          4.6          1.5         0.2                 0                0
5           1          5.0          1.4         0.2                 0                0
6           1          5.4          1.7         0.4                 0                0
```

So there are 3 predictor columns in `iris` but you end up with 5 (non-intercept) predictors.

Max

[1] This is why you need to provide a reproducible example. Often, when I get ready to ask a question, the answer becomes apparent while I take the time to write a good description of the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look more seriously later. However the value `mtry=5` in `randomForest(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = iris, mtry=5)` is not valid, then I don't understand why `train()` possibly returns such a value.

Comment: also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/mtry-tuning-given-by-caret-higher-than-the-number-of-predictors